# Use postgresql query results to form another query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select from one table using the select result from another table. I can run this in two queries but would like to optimize it into just one.

First query.. Select ids where matching other id

```
select id from lookuptable where paid = '547'
```

This results in something like this

6316352
6316353
6318409
6318410
6320468
6320469
6320470
6322526
6322527
6324586
6324587
6326648

I would like to then use this result to make another selection. I can do it manually like below. Note, there could be many rows with these values so I've been using a IN statement

```
select * from "othertable" where id in (6316352,6316353,6318409,6318410,6320468,6320469,6320470,6322526,6322527,6324586,6324587,6326648);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  ot.* 
from 
   "othertable" as ot 
join 
   lookuptable as lt 
on 
   ot.id = lt.id 
where 
    lt.paid = '547'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` operator supports not just [value lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) but also [subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN), so you can literally write

```
select * from "othertable" where id in (select id from lookuptable where paid = '547');
```